# Bootstrap: Custom CSS not working on button hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a button on my Bootstrap website change colour on hover to own my specification, but unfortunately it's not working no matter what I try! I'm using v3. Having the button depressed does show change.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Let's get started!</button>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.btn {
    font-family: "Raleway", cursive;
    background-color: #239799;
    border-color: #10c6d3;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn:hover {
    font-family: "Raleway", cursive;
    background-color: #10274c;
    border-color: #10c6d3;
}
```

**Updated CSS, still doesn't work, however.**

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn:hover {
    font-family: "Raleway", cursive;
    background-color: #10274c !important;
    border-color: #10c6d3 !important;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suppose you're using a predefined class btn, so you must to set !important to your attribute color to see the change

Comment: are you importing your css after or before bootstrap's css?

Comment: @TomaszRup Yes.

Comment: @ReneLimon I'll try it edit: didn't seem to work. Updated post

Comment: Try to select it with a selector that contains both classes of that button, like `.btn.btn-success { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `background-image` takes precedence  over `background-color`.
The `btn:active` selector defines the rule `background-image:none`. (somewhere in the bootstrap **theme** css)
The `btn:hover` never resets the `background-image`, therefore you see no difference in color when hovering over the button.

Add `background-image:none;` to your `.btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn:hover` selector and you''' notice that it does change.

```css
.btn.btn-primary {
  font-family: "Raleway", cursive;
  background-color: #239799;
  border-color: #10c6d3;
}

.btn.btn-primary:focus,
.btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary:hover {
  font-family: "Raleway", cursive;
  background-color: #10274c;
  border-color: #10c6d3;
}

#fixed:hover {
  background-image:none;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">i have a silly gradient as background</a>
<br><br>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="fixed">i'm fixed</a>
```

In the spirit of *give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime*, you can inspect the elements using the the chrome dev tools. Ticking mouse state specific selectors on and off for easy debugging.

[image: go fish]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "`class`" to define the style, try using "`id`".
im pretty sure bootstrap works by class, and doesn't like when you try to go over the top. either that or try and edit the styles from the right bootstrap sheet (check your `href`)

Comment: Hmm, ID doesn't seem to be working either. Strange. I guess I'll have to try edit the bootstrap stylesheet directly...

Answer (score 0):

But I can see in your own code the color's code are same. Do you think is this a reason? Or I can see that in your button using class="btn btn-success", so "btn-success" have own css. Need this also override?